# Equilateral triangles on the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have a triangle.
We then construct three points outside of the triangle by drawing three equilateral triangles on the sides of the original triangle.
Now we want to do the opposite: from the three points we constructed, we want to *construct* the original triangle. (With just a ruler and a compass)

How does that construction look like?

My idea was to use the Fermat point by drawing the same construction with the three  points (the Fermat point is the same).

[The construction of the Fermat point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Js3.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote the points like on this picture:

[image]

Consider the following composition of rotations: $I= R_{C',60^\circ}\circ R_{A',60^\circ}\circ R_{B',60^\circ}$. The classification of isometries says that $I$ is a central reflection, but also $I(A)=A$, so $I$ is the central reflection with respect to $A$: $I=S_A$. Thus $A$ can be constructed (e.g. take arbitrary $X$ and construct $X':=I(X)$; $A$ is the midpoint of $XX'$). In a similar way, by considering suitable compositions of rotations, you can construct $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Nice idea! Could you maybe state the classification theorem you mentioned or give a reference for it?

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi The only fact used here is that the composition $R_{B,\beta}\circ R_{A,\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are directed angles such that $\alpha+\beta\neq 0^\circ,\pm 360^\circ$, is again a rotation around some point $C$ for angle $\alpha+\beta$. I am sure that you can find this fact, as well as the whole classification of isometries, in classical books. E.g. Prasolov's Problems in Plane Geometry.